# Best way to "negate" an instanceof

Tags: java, syntax

I was thinking if there exists a better/nicer way to negate an `instanceof` in Java.
Actually, I'm doing something like:

```
if(!(myObject instanceof SomeClass)) { /* do Something */ }
```

But I think that a "beautiful" syntax to do this should exist.

Does anyone know if it exists, and how the syntax look like?

---

**EDIT:**
By beautiful, I might say something like this:

```
if(myObject !instanceof SomeClass) { /* do Something */ } // compilation fails
```

Comment: You could always create a variable, something like `boolean strIsString = str instanceof String;`...

Comment: yeah @Baqueta, is a option. But, what differences could happen in memory use in one syntax or another?

Comment: Your example is bad, because String can not have subclasses, so your example is basically an isNull check.

Answer (score 405, accepted):

No, there is no better way; yours is canonical.

Comment: Actually there can be like: if (!(obj instanceof String)) - Works just fine!

Comment: @arun That is the syntax that we all hate, and the original poster is asking how to avoid.

Answer (score 167):

I don't know what you imagine when you say "beautiful", but what about this? I personally think it's worse than the classic form you posted, but somebody might like it...

```
if (str instanceof String == false) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: About double logic, you could use `!= true` instead of `== false` :D

Comment: Seeing this helps me to understand that `if(!(str instanceof String))`  is the only right way, and I need to stop thinking alternatives

Comment: I like this solution since I am not required to build up a metal stack while reading it!

Comment: SonarLint will report an issue about this coding form (as a minor Code Smell), which message is: Remove the literal "false" boolean value.

Comment: static code checkers complain about this, but I prefer this, that small `!` character is so easy to overlook... And I'd say there is a lot of "us", e.g. StringUtils offers both `isBlank()` and `isNotBlank()` compared to `!isBlank()`...

Comment: Actually there can be like: if (!(obj instanceof String)) - Works just fine!

Answer (score 65):

You could use the [`Class.isInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29) method:

```
if(!String.class.isInstance(str)) { /* do Something */ }
```

... but it is still negated and pretty ugly.

Comment: is a little bit better, the excess parenthesis makes the code ugly, IMHO.

Comment: Isn't this a lot of slower?

Comment: This has different behaviour.  The instanceof keyword includes subclasses, the method does not, you need to use Class.isAssignableFrom to replicate the behaviour.

Comment: @ChrisCooper This is not true: `this method returns true if the specified Object argument is an instance of the represented class (or of any of its subclasses)`

Answer (score 33):

Usually you don't want just an `if` but an `else` clause as well.

```
if(!(str instanceof String)) { /* do Something */ } 
else { /* do something else */ }
```

can be written as

```
if(str instanceof String) { /* do Something else */ } 
else { /* do something */ }
```

Or you can write the code so you don't need to know if its a String or not. e.g.

```
if(!(str instanceof String)) { str = str.toString(); }
```

can be written as

```
str = str.toString();
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer here(first part)

Comment: This must be an acceptable answer as IntelliJ also suggested this method.

Comment: This might just be a "me" problem, but if not and others are in a similar situation, I wanted to at least add the comment that my first reading of the first part was "most of the time it's good practice to always include an `else` for your `if`, even if it's just a no-op", which I'd call bad advice. I now realize I misread that, but wanted to drop this note in case anyone else misreads it as well. Great answer!

Answer (score 13):

If you can use static imports, and your moral code allows them

```
public class ObjectUtils {
    private final Object obj;
    private ObjectUtils(Object obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public static ObjectUtils thisObj(Object obj){
        return new ObjectUtils(obj);
    }

    public boolean isNotA(Class<?> clazz){
        return !clazz.isInstance(obj);
    }
}
```

And then...

```
import static notinstanceof.ObjectUtils.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "";
        if (thisObj(a).isNotA(String.class)) {
            System.out.println("It is not a String");
        }
        if (thisObj(a).isNotA(Integer.class)) {
            System.out.println("It is not an Integer");
        }
    }    
}
```

This is just a fluent interface exercise, I'd never use that in real life code!
Go for your classic way, it won't confuse anyone else reading your code!

Comment: I don't like static imports.. anyway thanks for try to help :)

Answer (score 6):

If you find it more understandable, you can do something like this with Java 8 :

```
public static final Predicate<Object> isInstanceOfTheClass = 
    objectToTest -> objectToTest instanceof TheClass;

public static final Predicate<Object> isNotInstanceOfTheClass = 
    isInstanceOfTheClass.negate(); // or objectToTest -> !(objectToTest instanceof TheClass)

if (isNotInstanceOfTheClass.test(myObject)) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: With Java 11, this should work `if (Predicate.not(isInstanceOfTheClass).test(myObject)) { ...`. Not better, imo, but should work!

Answer (score 3):

ok just my two cents, use a is string method:

```
public static boolean isString(Object thing) {
    return thing instanceof String;
}

public void someMethod(Object thing){
    if (!isString(thing)) {
        return null;
    }
    log.debug("my thing is valid");
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve by doing below way.. just add a condition by adding bracket `if(!(condition with instanceOf))` with the whole condition by adding `!` operator at the start just the way mentioned in below code snippets.

```
if(!(str instanceof String)) { /* do Something */ } // COMPILATION WORK
```

instead of

```
if(str !instanceof String) { /* do Something */ } // COMPILATION FAIL
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree that in most cases the `if (!(x instanceof Y)) {...}` is the best approach, but in some cases creating an `isY(x)` function so you can `if (!isY(x)) {...}` is worthwhile.

I'm a typescript novice, and I've bumped into this S/O question a bunch of times over the last few weeks, so for the googlers the typescript way to do this is to create a typeguard like this:

*typeGuards.ts*

```
export function isHTMLInputElement (value: any): value is HTMLInputElement {
  return value instanceof HTMLInputElement
}
```

*usage*

```
if (!isHTMLInputElement(x)) throw new RangeError()
// do something with an HTMLInputElement
```

I guess the only reason why this might be appropriate in typescript and not regular js is that typeguards are a common convention, so if you're writing them for other interfaces, it's reasonable / understandable / natural to write them for classes too.

There's more detail about user defined type guards like this [in the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)