# The opposite of instanceof

Tags: java, instanceof

Is it possible to get the opposite of instanceof in java? I have tried code like this:

```
if( example !instanceof blarg)....
```

but it won't let me put the ! anywhere without an error, please help.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068150/best-way-to-negate-a-instanceof

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You have to negate the entire thing:

```
if(!(example instanceof blarg))
```

You could also write it like so:

```
if(example instanceof blarg == false)
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative make use of `isInstance` method:

```
   if (!example.class.isInstance(blarg))
   {
     // your code here
   }
```